# image_tag with javascript Rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can i edit this code ?

```
<img data-seq src="images/model1.png" />
```

For this , but using script - "data-seq":

```
<%= image_tag 'model1.png' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you want to add a custom `data-seq` value, use this:

```
<%= image_tag 'model1.png', data: { seq: '' } %>
```

Comment: I try to use Slider - **sequencejs** . what shoud i paste here to make it work ? - data: { seq: '' }

Comment: I don't know this tool, try to refer to documentation

Answer (score 0):

This will generate what you want

```
<%= image_tag 'model1.png', data: { seq: nil } %>
```